# Transposing and pivoting using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
SKU     44/2017    43/2017       42/2017  
AC1007  125       143            103
AC3488  88        79             84
```

I would like to transpose it to

```
SKU     Date           Actual
AC1007  44/2017        125
AC1007  43/2017        143
AC1007  42/2017        103
AC3488  44/2017         88
AC3488  43/2017         79
AC3488  42/2017         84
```

What I am trying to achieve here is a mix of transposing and pivoting , which is necessary for me to do further exploratory data analysis.

I would like to know how we can code this out?

Comment: `df.melt('SKU')`

Comment: Thank you @coldspeed , preciously what I wanted